# is there a structural analysis library from python?

Tags: python-3.x, finite-element-analysis

I want to find the maximum displacement in a 3-dimensional structural system

I have the coordinates of the end points of the beams

1. type of support
2. support points
3. material properties
4. cross section information
5. gravitation load

I don't need a library that takes into account everything a basic solver for a 3 dimensional structural system will also work

(i am actually looking for something like karamnba(for grasshopper) but for python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google found [SfePy](http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/index.html) as the first hit.

Stack Overflow isn't intended for these kinds of questions.  Please read the FAQ and try Google first next time.

I'd wonder why the implementation language is important to you.  Your problem is so simple that it'd be possible for any FEA solution to handle it without requiring code changes from you.  Why do you have to specify the programming language it's written in?

Update:

Now you've made it clear: You wish to plug this into a genetic algorithm and perform optimization.

How interesting.

Your problem description is for a linear structural model, so convergence of the FEA result is not an issue.

Convergence *will* be an issue for your GA.  I don't know that it's guaranteed.  You'll have explore your state space.

I am having trouble visualizing how you'll define your "chromasome", how you'll construct the initial population, vary and mutate it, etc.

Google found some good Python GA links: [this](https://pypi.org/project/pyeasyga/) and [that](https://github.com/DEAP/deap).

This is not an [out of the box problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20genetic%20algorithm%20for%20finite%20element%20analysis&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS790US790&oq=python%20genetic%20algorithm%20for%20finite%20element%20analysis&aqs=chrome..69i57.9022j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). You can vary geometry, materials, boundary conditions, loading, etc.

You'll need a lot of computing power, but fortunately the world is awash in CPU. All you need is a deep pocketbook.

Good luck.

Comment: need to use the solver as a fitness function for a genetic algorithm. only language i can currently understand is python and a little bit java. actually needed a suggestion to something that has a little graphical interface and converges fast for the same

Answer (score 3):

there is also python bindings for well known software `OpenSees`, documentation available at:
https://openseespydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/